# jQuery append href

Tags: jquery, append, href

I'm trying to append a link with jQuery, but it's not working. Here is my code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $( ".class" ).append( "<p><a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a></p>" );
});
```

Comment: your code is right but please fix your quotes. in double quotes you can use only one quote

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Fix your quotes:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $( ".class" ).append( "<p><a href='http://www.google.com'>Google</a></p>" );
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You have nested double quotes which is why it doesn't work. This will work (user outer single quotes):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $( ".class" ).append('<p><a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a></p>');
});
```